# Server.listeners is not a function

Tags: javascript, npm, websocket

I'm follow [this websockets tutorial](https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-socket-io-tutorial/#installing-socket-io) to learn how to integrate Socket.IO into an Angular project. I've followed the steps exactly but when I try to run my websockets server project I get the following error:

> TypeError: server.listeners is not a function
>       at Server.attach (\ws-server\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:455:26)

At line 455 of server.js we see this code

```
  // cache and clean up listeners
  var listeners = server.listeners('request').slice(0);
```

I am confused as to why I'm seeing this. I've updated both express and Socket.IO and I'm still seeing the same issue. I can provide the angular code if needed but I don't think it's related.

Here is what my server code looks like

```
let app = require('express')();
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')('http');

io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
    //Log when a user connects
    console.log('user connected');

    //Log when a client disconnects
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    //When we receive a message event from our client, print out the 
    //contents of that message and echo it back to our clients using emit()

    socket.on('message', (message)=>{
        console.log('message received: ' + message);
        io.emit('message', {type:'new-message', text: message});
    });
});

//initialize server on port 5000
http.listen(5000, () =>{
    console.log('started on port 500');
});
```

And here is the full error

> TypeError: server.listeners is not a function
>       at Server.attach (C:\Users***\Documents\poker game\ws-server\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:455:26)
>       at Function.attach (C:\Users***\Documents\poker game\ws-server\node_modules\engine.io\lib\engine.io.js:124:10)
>       at Server.initEngine (C:\Users***\Documents\poker game\ws-server\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:310:21)
>       at C:\Users***\Documents\poker game\ws-server\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:295:10
>       at Encoder.encode (C:\Users***\Documents\poker game\ws-server\node_modules\socket.io-parser\index.js:135:5)
>       at Server.listen.Server.attach (C:\Users***\Documents\poker game\ws-server\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:290:16)
>       at new Server (C:\Users***\Documents\poker game\ws-server\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:59:17)
>       at Server (C:\Users***\Documents\poker game\ws-server\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:44:41)
>       at Object. (C:\Users***\Documents\poker game\ws-server\index.js:3:30)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)

Comment: angular is in the frontend , and your websocket server is in the backend , the error has nothing to do with angular

Comment: Agreed. That's why I said I believe it's unrelated. That being said, I am new to this stuff so there could be something critical I was omitting so I just wanted to cover my bases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your server to this , I didnt test it yet but it should work

```
 var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
   io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

    http.listen(5000, function(){
      console.log('listening on *:5000');
    });
```

I am not familiar with Angular but , this is how your code should look like in the front end using JQuery

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

You accidentally passed in a string literal `('http')` instead of your `(http)` variable name.

Change this:

```
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')('http');
```

To this:

```
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

I made the same mistake myself today. :)